# Centralising Discs to Repository?

Tags: bash, networking

I have discs where is much variations. I would like to add the files of many OS to my central repository where the files originating from OS X have caused me biggest trouble when later viewing them in Linux distros or Windows

1. files/discs made in OS X
2. files/discs made in many Linus distros (mostly Debians and Ubuntus)
3. only some files/discs made in Chromebook [formatting here a disc and using it in other systems - a nightmare so just reject this target]
4. only a few files/discs made in Windows 7 and 10

However, I am getting warnings about ownership. 
I am thinking of running

```
sudo chown -R masi:masi /local/folder
```

However, masi is not the main user in all my systems. My repository distributes the files to many computers, phones and laptops. So a problem when using there. 
I do `ls -la` and notice that `drwxr-xr-x 1 99 99 ...` where I think 99 99 are group and owner, respectively. Some files/folders have `root root` instead.

I am not sure how I should control the group and owner here. Should I put everything to `99 99`?

### BTsync's Archive to Prevent Damage of ransomware attacks

I contacted the BTsync support after L33tCh's answer and received the answer

> Sync doesn't defend users from virus
>   attacks. When files appeared inside shared folder and peer has
>   read-write permissions Sync transfer files to another peers. But if
>   Archive option is enabled you will be able to find previous file
>   versions even if they were overwritten by encrypted file versions.
>
> So potentially you can download infected files from another peers. But
>   if you don't have antivirus program you can do that even when you surf
>   the internet.
>
> The link says that user's colleague encountered ransomware attack, not
>   Sync. They didn't affect our servers nor Sync binary files on our
>   servers. So you don't need to worry about it.

They have the following parameter `max_file_size_for_versioning` with value integer and default 1000 (Mb) which means that if file is too big and was modified Sync will put previous version in the Archive.
The Archive folder is located in the `.sync/Archive` folder inside shared folder. On Windows and Mac you can open it by right-clicking on the folder in the Sync and choosing "Open Archive" option.
The `max archive file age` is now called `sync_trash_ttl` (change to 2.3), updated by my request [here](http://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/204754239) in Preferences > Settings. Set it to 0 for infinite archive.

The infinite file storage in archive consumes much memory. 
Assume many small changes in .tex files, for instance, which creates many files in Archive. 
I think GIT could handle this problem. 
I asked the thing from the support.

---

How can you centralise files/folders of discs to a repository for use with front-end and back-end devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MelBursian is correct in his answer.  Your users and groups must be mapped to the same UIDs and GIDs on all UNIX systems or you'll get owner and permissions errors when trying to access files created on other machines.

OSX uses the same setup as UNIX, as far as I can tell, so the same rules apply.

Windows has a completely different permissions system.  There is no standard way of mapping UNIX permissions to Windows permissions.

What I suspect is happening here is BTSync is copying permissions between UNIX and OSX machines without modifying the owner or group for the files (remember, it's the UID and GID *numbers* that are important, not the user and group *names*).  It has to modify the ones from Windows to some extent, which is probably why your Windows files are mostly working.

On-the-fly user permission modification is a feature of BTSync Pro, apparently (I've never used it).  I'm not sure if it can do what you need it to do, though.  If you're using Pro, you should contact their support and find out how to solve your problem.  If you're not using Pro, then you should modify your users and groups to map to the correct UIDs and GIDs.

MacOS has a user permissions tool that I believe can fix permissions once you change your UID and GID.  On UNIX, once you make the change you'll need to use something like `find` to change owners and groups where necessary.  Example commands are below - assume masi:masi maps to 105:105 and you need it to be 99:99, and you've already changed /etc/passwd and /etc/group:

`find / -uid 105 -exec chown masi {} \;`

`find / -gid 105 -exec chown :masi {} \;`

Make backups first, and be sure there are no UID or GID collisions during the process (i.e. two user with the same UID, or two groups with the same GID).

The alternative and safer option is to create a script for each machine that runs commands like the above, but only for the directories you're syncing.  Run that script every time you sync (maybe evoke BTSync and the appropriate commands from the same script).  You'll need `sudo` for this.

Oh, and since you're using OSX and Windows, forget about the NIS comments I made above.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite putting everything in the same place but at least let's you access all you need as if it is. It should get around your access issues by having each platform on it's own system and let you see all your sources as a single Drive or however you decide to set it up.

https://infinit.sh/

They describe it as a Decentralized Software‑Based File Storage Platform

I'm planning on using it myself to have a single point of access into my laptop/home and cloud drives from a single point. There are then clients for each platform to access the data in a similar way to how DropBox works.

This should replace the need for BTSync but also give you the option to add the security of a version controlled storage system. The reason I bring this up is a colleague lost a bunch of data when he was hit with a ransomware attack and BTSync did it's job but it meant all copies of the data was then encrypted and lost. Only the set that was also in a cloud storage system was recoverable.

Comment: I sent this forward to BTsync support. I hope they can do something against ransomware attacks.

Comment: I am profiling now infinit.sh. It does not seem to have two-step login. Username and password is also stored in their server.

Comment: I received an answer from BTsync. You can omit such situations by using the version history by BTsync. I am trying to find how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

unless you have a centralized or very consistent tracking of usernames/groupnames versus UID/GID definitions, it is unavoidable to see usernames as owners of the file on some places while others just display numbers like 99 99, And despite what you see and think, file ownerships are based on those numbers, not the usernames.

Lets say, you are masi:masi (user:group) on server1 and UID of masi is 99 and GID of masi is 99. You have changed the ownership of the files you want to masi:masi. Let's say same directory is shared by server2. On server2, your masi username has UID 105 and GID is 105 as well. When you go to the server2, you can not access those files you just changed the ownerships on server1.

Therefore, if you wnat centrally accesible files, make sure your UID and GID are the same all across the board. Or, you can open permissions to read and write from/to them, but, so to anyone else who stumbles upon them.

Comment: Just adding a point: This is the kind of problem NIS was made to solve.  It's not the only way, but it's easy and works with pretty much any UNIX out of the box.

Comment: @JeffSpaulding Can you please explain more about NIS.

Comment: NIS stand for Network Information System.  It's a Sun thing, but pretty much every UNIX can use it.  It keeps a central database of several of your files, including the password file.  When you're running NIS, you have the same UID no matter what machine you log into, which makes things like NFS work a lot better.  It's insecure, so don't run it somewhere you don't trust.  It also does name resolution for your local network, so if you don't have a local DNS server, it'll take care of your hosts file for you.  There's tons of documentation around, just do a search.

Comment: @JeffSpaulding How do you classify it insecure? I am planning to use BTsync as the server application in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, where I still need to solve the ownership thing, since I have to merge many discs there. Linux should be fairly secure in this kind of setting. NIS may still be needed there, not sure.

Comment: I'm not an expert at NIS, BTW, so someone with more experience with it can tell you more.  What I do know is that it's relatively easy to spoof users, and there's no encryption.  NFS has a lot of the same issues (they were designed to work together and are designed in a very similar fashion), so most of what people say about NFS being insecure also applies to NIS.  I don't know your setup; if you have users come and go, then NIS is worth considering.  If you rarely add or remove users, then you'd probably be fine just making sure all machines mapped the same UIDs to the same users.

Comment: @JeffSpaulding  I added description of the setting in the body. OS X files and discs are causing now most trouble.

Comment: NIS is very old technology and relatively insecure; anyone can access the password database for example. I would instead recommend using a general purpose management tool like one of : "puppet, chef, cfengine, ansible, salt" to distribute users across your systems. They all work in much the same way. A central server runs a management engine containing the configuration to distribute, and an agent runs on the clients making sure that they are all correctly configured.